# CreateCaret color wrong?

Tags: windows, winapi, text

I have create a caret with a bitmap which is red as follows:
[image: red_caret]

code:

```
HBITMAP hbm = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2));
::CreateCaret(hWnd_, hbm, 0, 0);
::ShowCaret(hWnd_);
```

but the caret turns out to be 
[image]

Is there anything wrong with my code, or CreateCaret just shift the color bits in the bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, windows inverse the bitmap bits. So, red(0xffff0000) becomes cyan(0xff00ffff); Black becomes white, and white becomes black.